# Google API Key for a dynamic IP server

Tags: php, google-api, ip, google-places-api, dynamic-ip

I need to use the **Google Places API** through PHP in a Wordpress site hosted on Flywheel.

It seems the option I need to use is the *IP addresses (web servers, cron jobs, etc.)*.

**My problem is that flywheel has a dynamic IP address system and after a couple of days the API stops working since the IP has changed.**

I' trying to see if I can authenticate the site using something else but I have not been able to find it. 
I've looked at [googleapis/google-api-php-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client) but the Places API is not part of the APIs the package can connect.

Do you know how If there is any other way to whitelist a site for a web server with a dynamic IP?

Comment: You can connect your server to VPN to get static IP.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution or are you still looking for a way? If yes, please let me know in my post if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

**It's not necessary to use the API key restriction. You don't need to restrict it by an IP address. It's an optional feature per key.**

I'll try to give you at least an option/suggestion because I'm not sure how you intent to use the Google Place API but you can basically create 2 separate keys:

- **One public API key** for browser based calls (show map, suggestions, etc..). In this case I would use HTTP referrer for as restriction and add your websites where this key is running.
- **One private API key** for server based calls (server2server, queue, cronjobs, etc..). Since you have a floating IP you would need to know the full range. In this case I would not "additionally" restrict it by the IP address and only use the secret.

Another suggestions in case your *really* *really* want to restrict this additionally:

- Ask flywheel if they can give you a dedicated IP address. A quick google lookup showed some forums which indicate that they support it. Attention: I'm sure they will charge you for this additional money.
- Move your cronjobs, queues, ... away from flywheel and host it somewhere, where you have control of the IP address. (e.g. AWS EC3 t3.nano with an elastic ip address - costs you ~$5/month)

Hope this helps and gives you some impressions about your options. Let me know if this answers your question or if you need and further information.